# XCode: Corrupt Project? Can't open in XCode or move project files

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been working on an XCode project for the past few months and it has suddenly stopped responding. When the project is opened in XCode it hangs and then freezes on the "Loading ProjectName" Screen. I also cannot duplicate the project in finder as it hangs with 'preparing files' message and cannot move the files from the ICloud to other folders as it hangs with the same 'preparing files' message.

I am using the latest versions of XCode and swift. All my other projects open. The project is saved in the ICloud Desktop. The problem initially appeared after I installed a new pod (this pod to be specific: https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenSSL-Universal) with the project still open in XCode (doh!) which caused it to freeze.

I have tried opening the project 20 - 30 times since then and it has frozen all but one time. The one time it didn't freeze everything worked fine, but when I closed and reopened the project it began freezing again. I have tried deleting the saved application state, derived data and xcuserdata.

I am wondering what the next steps I can take are?